# How to remove an image from physical path in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to delete an image from physical path say
 `@" E:\Inetpub\vhosts\website.com\website2.com\images\abc.jpg`. What should i do for this?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you atleast search how to do this? If you did what have you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward using the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class.

```
string path=@" E:\Inetpub\vhosts\website.com\website2.com\images\abc.jpg";
if(File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Delete(path);
}
```

You application must have access of that folder.

### Edit 1

```
string path=Server.MapPath(@"images\abc.jpg");
if(File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Delete(path);
}
```

Comment: File.Exists(path) returns false

Comment: means file does not exist on that path.

Comment: See my edit you need to use `server.map` path to get the physical path of your image.

Comment: i need to delete the image from another directory

Comment: then your application must have the delete permission of that directory. Other Wise you can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your application identity has the permissions, you can call [File.Delete(filePath)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) to delete the file. Also, there's no need to check if the file exists as per the remarks on MSDN.

> If the file to be deleted does not exist, no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Use ListView/Repeater show file.

```
//Load file:

using System.IO;

DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"));

lvImages.DataSource = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
lvImages.DataBind();
```

//Delete:

```
protected void lvImages_ItemDeleting(object sender, ListViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        string fileName = ((Literal)lvImages.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("ltrImagePath")).Text;
        fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
        File.Delete(fileName);
    }
    catch { }
}
```